# Взаимодействие с# кода и Js скрипта с SignalR

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь понять взаимодействие метода с# и функции js скрипта.

Js скрипт:

```
   $(function () {

    var chat = $.connection.myHub;


    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

        $('#mybutton').click(function () {
            var message = 'Hello';
            chat.server.send(message);

            chat.client.addMessage = function (returnmessage) {

                $('#mytext').text(returnMessage);
            }
        });

    });
})
```

КОД НА С#:

```
    namespace ChatSignal
{
    [HubName("myHub")]
    public class MyHub : Hub
    {    
        public void Send(string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

КОД HTML:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mytext"> 
    </div>
    <button id="mybutton">Click</button>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/MyFile.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Переменную на сервер я получаю...но в скриптовый метод addMessage я её не возвращаю...почему?

Comment: Подозреваю, что all отправляет всем кроме текущего.

Comment: Вызов метода на всех клиентах: Clients.All.addMessage(message); Изучаю с метанита... там прописанны все методы.

Comment: что-то я не понял в чем вопрос, вроде все складно написано.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем ясен ваш вопрос. Попробую объяснить, что происходит в данном коде, хотя знатоком упомянутых технологий и не являюсь.

После того как вы установили соединение с сервером:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
```

вы добавляете обработчик нажатия кнопки отправки сообщения

```
   $('#mybutton').click(function () {
        var message = 'Hello';
        chat.server.send(message);

        .... 
    });
```

Теперь при нажатии кнопки `#mybutton`, вы отправляете сообщение `hello` серверу (`chat.server`), используя метод `send`. С серверной стороны имеется одноименный метод, который соответственно и вызывается:

```
public void Send(string message)
{
    Clients.All.addMessage(message);
}
```

Здесь сервер получил сообщение и отправляет его всем клиентам (`Clients.All`), методом `addMessage`. Теперь на стороне всех клиентов должен обработаться js-метод `addMessage`.

Обработчик данного метода на стороне клиента вы установили (вопрос вызывает только место, где это происходит):

```
        chat.client.addMessage = function (returnmessage) {
            $('#mytext').text(returnMessage);
        }
```

И вот когда сервер отправил всем сообщение, вызывается этот обработчик события, который и добавляет строку, полученную от сервера (и ранее принятую им от вас) к `#mytext`. Этот метод будет срабатывать для всех входящих сообщений чата, в т.ч. от других клиентов.

На этом в общем-то все и заканчивается. Вопрос возникает только к тому, что назначение обработчика `chat.client.addMessage` происходит при первой отправке сообщения. В связи с этим, вы не увидите ни одного входящего сообщения, пока не отправите в чат что-нибудь сами.

Comment: Так какая разница первое это или десятое сообщение...скрипт должен его принимать. Можно пример кода как нужно сделать.

Comment: @РоманПетров очевидно, вынести назначение `chat.client.addMessage` выше в `start().done()`  вместо `$('#mybutton').click` ?

Comment: Я понял. Благодарю.