# Реально ли создать чат без хранилища данных?

Tags: php, ajax

Возможно вопрос немного глупый, может даже не немного. Но мне интересно, возможно ли создать некий прототип чата без баз данных и других хранилищ? То есть на сколько я знаю можно подключить пользователей между собой, тогда каждый подключенный юзер будет как само хранилище.

Вопрос какие технологии при этом нужны? Как примерно это работает? Это теоретический вопрос, я надеюсь увидеть какие-то советы и обьяснения на тему почему это полезно или нет, и куда нужно смотреть на случай попытки реализации.

Comment: Если вам не нужно хранить историю сообщений, дак зачем и хранилище? А если нужно, то хранилище то или иное будет. Можно и в локальных данных браузера хранить историю, но там объем ограничен и одним движением руки все похерить можно.

Comment: @teran Я не понимаю как это заставить работать. Обычно это как работает: пользователь пишет сообщение, оно летит в базу, другой проверяет есть ли в базе что-то новое, закачивает его себе и так постоянно, верно? А куда смотреть за новым сообщением если хранилища нет?

Comment: вообще не обязательно. Сервер может отсылать сообщения клиентам. [Вот к примеру свежий вопрос на вашу тему по родственным технологиям: `ASP.net + SignalR`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/713997/223826). В общем гуглите на тему пхп и сокетов.

Comment: В общих словах: запускаете процесс-демон, который висит постоянно и принимает соединения, и все нужные для работы чата данные хранятся в оперативной памяти у этого процесса (историю сообщений тоже можно хранить, только, очевидно, пропадёт при перезапуске)

Comment: Приходилось делал. Использовал sharedmemory http://php.net/manual/ru/book.shmop.php.

Comment: @Воробьев Александр я полагаю хранилище тогда - оперативная память сервера, так что по сути не подходит под тему вопроса. К тому же мне кажется эффективнее использовать сокеты, не нагружая сервер так сильно. (п.с. если я не прав повравьте меня)

Comment: Можно и без PHP. С помощью WebRTC и публичного сервера-сигнальщика можно соединять клиентов напрямую. [Пробовал, работает (осторожно, ClojureScript, но собирается в обычный JS)](https://github.com/D-side/rtc-chat) (хотя не всегда, бывают сети, которые здорово затрудняют установление прямых соединений).

Comment: @D-side Спасибо за комментарий. Меня все устраивает в PHP пока что :) Когда освобожуть почитаю подробнее про все что тут написали и закрою вопрос, если этого будет достаточно.

Comment: @Telion в общем вы правы, на том проекте не было возможности использовать сокеты. Суть в том что это работало. Порядка полуторасотен человек постоянно сидели на связи. И это на виртуальном хостинге.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать технологию веб-сокет. 2 пользователя подключаются к серверу, как только первый отправляет сообщение, сервер тут же отсылает его второму, нигде не сохраняя.

Если интересно, мой пример такого чата на `node.js` (с шифрованием): https://github.com/Zergatul/zChat

Comment: На Node.js я по гайдам такое уже делал, пытаюсь понять как без гайдов на PHP создать :)

Comment: Язык программирования не имеет значения, веб сокеты - это не фича языка, а сетевой протокол.

Comment: Может я что-то не понимаю(что и так очевидно), но способы управления протоколами разные в разных языках. То что вы написали программу на node.js может далеко не всегда означать что вы сможете повторить это на PHP без лишней помощи.